# Binding Window1 Icon to MainWindow Icon

Tags: wpf, xaml

I tried following code but it doesnt work. Any suggestions?

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="Window1" x:Name="Window1" Title="Window1" 
    Height="300" Width="300"
    Icon="{Binding ElementName=Application.Current.MainWindow, Path=Icon}" >

<Grid>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<Window ...
   Icon="{Binding Path=MainWindow.Icon, Source={x:Static Application.Current}}">

    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```